# Adding a 1 to each element not zero, matlab

Tags: matlab, vector

My vector `RVE` that is stored, I just want to add a one to each element that is not zero. so every non zero element is left alone and every number that is not `0` in the matrix a `1` will be added to it.

eg:

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] -> [2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]

[5 3 1 0 0 0 0 0] -> [6 4 2 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Code:

```
n=100;
primlist=2; % starting the prime number list


for numba=1:n;
   if mod(2+numba,primlist)~=0
      primlist=[primlist;2+numba]; %generating the prime number list
   end
end


for numbas=2:n
    prims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pprims=zeros(size(primlist));
    pow=prims;
    for k=1:10
        for i=1:length(primlist) % identifying each primes in the primlist
            if mod(numbas,primlist(i).^k)==0
                prims(i)=primlist(i); % sum of all the powers of prims, such that prims divide numbas
                pow(i)=k; % collecting the exponents of primes
            end

            if primlist(i)<=numbas
               pprims(i)=primlist(i);
            end
        end


    PPRIMS=pprims' % primes less than or equal to numbas   
    PRIMS=prims'; % primes that divide numbas
    POW=pow'; % highest prower of primes that divide numbas

    PPV(numbas,:)=PRIMS; % saving prims
    PVE(numbas,:)=POW; % Saving Pows
    PLV(numbas.:)=PPRIMS % saving PPRIMS
    numbas;


    RVE=cumsum(PVE); % the cummulative sum of the exponents of PVE
    %RVE1(numbas,:)=RVE

      for x=1:26

        RVE(numbas,x);
        if x~=0
            RVE1=RVE(numbas,x+1)
        end
      end

%sigmafac=(prod(PPV.^(RVE(numbas)+1)-1))/((prod(PPV-1))) 
end



end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logical indexing approach:

```
RVE=[5 3 1 0 0 0 0 0];
RVE(RVE~=0)=RVE(RVE~=0)+1;
```

Result:

```
RVE =

     6     4     2     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RVE = RVE + (RVE ~= 0)
```

The conditional portion above will return a Matrix/Vector of 1s (element is not 0) and 0s (element is 0).  Add this result back to the original Matrix.

Comment: Elegant alternative to my answer. Highlight your code appropriately and I'll give you my vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for example:

```
x = [1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0];
y = x+(x~=0);
```

Comment: @tmpearce: Edit's within 5 mins after posting an answer / question are not shown (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130127/new-edit-to-same-answer-is-not-showing)

Answer (score 1):

`RVE(RVE~=0)` selects each non zero element. To add 1 use

```
RVE(RVE~=0)=RVE(RVE~=0)+1
```